# 3D holographic image reconstruction in optics

Tags: optics, hologram

I am trying to understand how 3D reconstruction of holographic images work. I have a basic knowledge of the holography principle in optics, and that there are several methods for phase retrieval and back-propagation of light in order to reconstruct/refocus the image. Let's assume that we have an *inline digital holographic microscopy* setup, and a digital camera (CMOS) for capturing the holographic image. We also have access to a code to obtain the phase of the hologram and to refocus the image at different distances from the CMOS plane. Since the object whose holographic image was captured was a 3D object--has depth--I need to know how to find the depth of it. All reconstructed images we see are just 2D images though. What do I need to do to find the depth information? Any help is much appreciated!